# How to By pass first Row on Excel in foreach loop?

Tags: c#

I have this Code for Reading Excell Records:

```
public IEnumerable<FillinEntity> Map(IEnumerable<ExcelRow> excelRows)
            {

                List<FillinEntity> fillinEntities = new List<FillinEntity>();

                foreach (ExcelRow row in excelRows)
                {

                    FillinEntity excell = new FillinEntity();
                    excell.SerialNumber = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0]);
                    excell.PalletNumber = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1]);
                    excell.Location = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2]);
                    excell.CreatedBy = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3]);

                    fillinEntities.Add(excell);

                }

                return fillinEntities;
            }
```

I have this records: And it succesfully inserted

```
R03091294   2    2  FGROOM  RYAN
```

My Problem: I Add column header on the excell sheet.

```
Serial Number    Pallet      Location   CreatedBy -----> i need to by pass column header.
R03091294   2    2         FGROOM     RYAN
```

Thanks in regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool is_first_row = True;
foreach (ExcelRow row in excelRows)
{
   if(is_first_row)
   {
      is_first_row = false;
      continue;
   }
    ...
}
....
```

```
.Skip(1)
```

**[solution provided by Codesleuth is much better option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475269/how-to-by-pass-first-row-on-excel-in-foreach-loop/3475284#3475284).**

Answer (score 4):

You could always just skip it:

```
foreach (ExcelRow row in excelRows.Cast<ExcelRow>().Skip(1))
```

See [`Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx).

*Note: I used `Cast<ExcelRow>()` in case your enumerable `excelRows` can't be resolved to `ExcelRow`.*

Comment: I am getting `the type or namespace for ExcelRow could not be found`. Any idea what might be going on here?